# C# Splitting Strings on `#` character

Tags: c#

just wondering for example, if I had the string:

`Hello#World#Test`

How would I remove the # and then have `Hello`, `World` and `Test` in three seperate strings, for example called:
`String1` and `String2` and `String3`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can have them in an array of strings doing something as easy as this:

```
string[] s = "Hello#World".Split('#');
```

`s[0]` contains "Hello", and `s[1]` contains "World"

See here for more information on split: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`String.Split("#".ToCharArray())` will return a `string[]` with two elements.

Element0 will be "Hello", and Element1 will be "World"

Answer (score 1):

This is one way

```
"hello#world".Split('#');
```