# C# Loading Data From Text file integers

Tags: c#, string, file, load, int

i have a small problem with my text-based RPG in c# console.

I have made a method to save and that works but when i want to load it gives me an error..

here is my code for loading :

(the strings don't give a error but the problems start from Level to Agility)

code :

```
public static void LoadData ()
{
        // create reader & open file
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("SavedGame.txt");

        // read lines of text
        string xCoordString = tr.ReadLine();
        string yCoordInt= tr.ReadLine();

        //Convert the strings to int
        Name = Convert.ToString(xCoordString);
        PlayerType = Convert.ToString (xCoordString);
        Level = Convert.ToString(xCoordString);
        HP = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
        Strenght = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
        Intelligence = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
        Agility = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? You may need to step through your code and see the value of each variable you were trying to convert

Comment: Level = Convert.ToInt32 btw instead of ToString

Comment: and error was : System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Convert.ToInt32 (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at practiceCSHARP.MainClass.LoadData () [0x0002f] in /home/stefano/Projects/practiceCSHARP/practiceCSHARP/Main.cs:396
  at practiceCSHARP.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x002eb] in /home/stefano/Projects/practiceCSHARP/practiceCSHARP/Main.cs:109

Comment: Can you show what your text file looks like?

Comment: what is put into level is the int number 3

Comment: Stefano
Knight
1
100
3
3
3
 is the text file

Comment: no each line seperate Brandon

Comment: The code makes no sense. I don't see where you loop through the lines?  you are converting the same value (`xCoordString`) into several different variables: `Name`, `PlayerType`, etc. Am I missing somthing?

Comment: It looks like you are only calling read line twice, if each value is on a separate line you would need to loop through to get all the values. As your code stands xCoordString = Stefano, yCoordInt = Knight

Comment: so how could i fix this??

Comment: Full saving and Loading methods (SAVING WORKS!)

Comment: public static void SaveData ()
  {
   TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedGame.txt");

   // write lines of text to the file
   tw.WriteLine (Name);
   tw.WriteLine (PlayerType);
   tw.WriteLine(Level);
   tw.WriteLine(HP);
   tw.WriteLine (Strenght);
   tw.WriteLine(Intelligence);
   tw.WriteLine (Agility);

   // close the stream     
   tw.Close();
  }

Comment: // create reader & open file
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("SavedGame.txt");

    // read lines of text
    string xCoordString = tr.ReadLine();
    string yCoordInt= tr.ReadLine();

    //Convert the strings to int
    Name = Convert.ToString(xCoordString);
    PlayerType = Convert.ToString (xCoordString);
    Level = Convert.ToInt32(xCoordString);
    HP = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
    Strenght = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
    Intelligence = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
    Agility = Convert.ToInt32(yCoordInt);
    // close the stream
    tr.Close();
  }

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is being read into your variables is not convertible to an int. You may have to strip newline/carriage return characters, or the data just plain isn't numeric. You should test it and/or sanitize it before you try to convert it.

Comment: hmm can you maybe change to code to working? im just a beginner lol haha

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you doing

```
           string xCoordString = tr.ReadLine();
            //Convert the strings to int
           Name = Convert.ToString(xCoordString);
```

Why you string convert to string ???

So You read string , then you should split it

```
           string[] s = xCoordString .Split(' ');
```

then

```
           var firstVariable=s[0];
           var secondVariable=s[1];
```

and so on.  This should help You 
[C# Splitting Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

And one more:  use

```
        int.Parse(string value)
```

Hopefully my answer will helps You. Good luck !

Comment: This is not an answer. It's more of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `TryParse(String, Int32)` to check if a parse succeeded, and perform some action (like setting a default value, or notifying the user) if it doesn't succeed.

You can clean the input string then parse it:

```
private static int ParseNumber(string input)
{
             string cleanedInput = input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToString();
             int result;
             if (!Int32.TryParse(cleanedInput, out result))
             {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured..");
             }
     return result;

}
```

and just use `Agility = ParseNumber(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not parsing your save file correctly.  If this is the format of your save file:

```
Stefano 
Knight 
1 
100 
3 
3 
3
```

then you will need to iteratively read each line and parse the value read into your variables, as such:

```
string line = string.Empty;

//Convert the strings to int
line = tr.ReadLine();
Name = line;
line = tr.ReadLine();
PlayerType = line;
line = tr.ReadLine();
Level = Convert.ToInt32(line);
line = tr.ReadLine();
HP = Convert.ToInt32(line);
line = tr.ReadLine();
Strenght = Convert.ToInt32(line);
line = tr.ReadLine();
Intelligence = Convert.ToInt32(line);
line = tr.ReadLine();
Agility = Convert.ToInt32(line);
```

Of course there's better ways to manage your save-file data, but this should show you why your parsing didn't work.

Comment: WORKS!!@#$%*(*&$#@!@#$%*

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the lines like so, however you would need to determine which attribute it was and treat it accordingly.

```
 TextReader tr = new StreamReader("SavedGame.txt");


 string charInfo;
 while ((charInfo = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
     //parse the line and put into appropriate variable.
 }
```