# Splitting one String into two?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm creating an application where it saves a file according to whats enter into a couple of textboxes.
Example: I have a subject textbox which equals "test" and a messagebody textbox which equals "test123", the file saved would look like this:

```
[Subject]
test
[Body]
test123
```

There is also a string that equals all the contents of the file. I want to basically open and read the file (already done and working), then write everything between "[Subject]" and "[Body]" to be written to the subject textbox. Also write everything after "[Body]" to the messagebody textbox.

Comment: Is your format of [Subject] ... [Body] absolutely necessary? You could use other formats like XML or even JSON

Comment: Consider if broadly used file formats JSON, XML are acceptable. Otherwise please show code you have problem with.

Comment: Is this the entire file, or is the entire file exactly like that?  If either of those is yes, you can just do this by reading specific line numbers rather than dealing with regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Splitting Strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
var arr = txt.Replace("[Subject]","").Split(new string[]{"[Body]"}),
subject = arr[0],
body = arr[1];
```

Comment: I keep getting an error. "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @FadeShotEdits check out now

Comment: Works Perfectly. One little problem, that isn't a huge issue, the message body starts with a blank line.