# Get a value between specific chars in a string?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I got a string like, "house1_508_17.5_end003". Basically I want get 508, 17.5 out of this string.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on getting values from a string. Please read some and see if ideas there are applicable to your case. If not - make sure to update your post with what approaches you've tried and how to verify if code provided in answer actually answers the question. Also please check methods of `String` class - you may find something useful there.

Comment: You could take a look on `string.Split` and `double.TryParse` these are what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the `_` character.

```
string s = "house1_508_17.5_end003";
string[] digits = s.Split('_');
foreach (string digit in digits)
{
     Console.WriteLine(digit);
}
```

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) for `String.Split`. The documentation has good examples. This question might also be considered a duplicate. See this [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)