# How can I split the code in csharp

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to store some string code in SQL like `120.002.123` or `EXP.120.555`. How can I split those strings to increase only the rightmost integer part? I don't want to change other parts of the string.

Ex. `120.002.124` or `EXP.120.556`

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Why are you storing it as a string if you want to increment it? What code have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
string str = "EXP.120.556"; //120.002.123
str = String.Join(
                    ".", 
                    str.Split('.')
                        .Take(
                                str.Split('.').Length - 1
                             )
                 ) 
                 + "." + 
                 (
                    Convert.ToInt32
                    (
                        str.Split('.').LastOrDefault()
                    ) + 1
                 ).ToString();
```

So here in the code the first `String.Join` will join the other part of the string with `.` except of the last part which you want to increament using `Take`. Then `Convert.ToInt32` will convert the last part of the string to a integer using `LastOrDefault` and then we add 1 to it and again convert it back to string using `ToString`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use `String.Split` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and split by `.` to get each individual number.

```
string test = "120.002.123";
string[] allparts = test.Split('.');
```

Then take the last entry and [convert it to an integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int lastNumber = Convert.ToInt32(allparts.Last());
```

Now you can do what ever you want with that integer.

With a little more research effort you could have solved it on your own.
Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings) + [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)