# How Browse in php web page with c#

Tags: c#

i want use c# for get php web page and browse it For Looking for a badge character in this
for example:

```
var paths = {'root':'../../../../images/uploaded/', 'root_title':'Root Folder'};
```

i want browse php source code for "var paths" line.
and split this.

which method in c# can helo me for this!
tnx for answer me.

Comment: [How to parse strings using String.Split (C# Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Splitting Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559121/c-sharp-splitting-strings)

Comment: no this is not answer to my question i want looking for a tag or char in php source page

Comment: If you are not the owner of the php code you wont be able to parse it since the server will only deliver html and javascript code to you

Comment: i send a request and get webpage source code but i want get var paths = {'root':'../../../../images/uploaded/', 'root_title':'Root Folder'}; this line code